# NameError: name 'buildtree' is not defined

Tags: python

The problem is about a 2 decision tree.I want to build them but it show me this message: "NameError: name 'buildtree' is not defined".It is simple mistake but I am new to python so any help will be good.Thanks

```
if __name__ == "__main__":


    att1=float(input())
    att2=float(input())
    att3=float(input())
    att4=float(input())
    planttype=input()
    testCase=[att1,att2,att3,att4,planttype]

    tmp = [att1, att2, att3, att4]
    p1 = []
    p2 = []
    leng = len(trainingData)

    for i in range(0,int(leng/2)):
        p1.append(trainingData[i])
    for i in range(int(leng/2),len(trainingData)):
        p2.append(trainingData[i])

    d1 = buildtree(p1)
    d2 = buildtree(p2)

    print('Drvo 1')
    printtree(d1)
    print('Drvo 2')
    printtree(d2)

    k1 = classify(tmp,d1)
    k2 = classify(tmp,d2)

    print (k1)
    print (k2)

    if (k1 == k2):
        print (k1)
    else:
        print('KONTRADIKCIJA')
    t=build_tree(trainingData)
    print(classify(testCase,t))
```

Comment: Well, where did you *define* `buildtree`? It's not a built-in function.

Comment: You are calling custom functions in your code, but there are *no* functions in this posting.  You definitely omitted an important part of your question.  If you *do* have functions somewhere, did you perhaps misspell `build_tree`?  You use that name elsewhere.

Comment: As a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning problems with code like your's, it is required that you extract and provide a [mcve].